# Cordova Ionic 3 deviceready not fired on android 6

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic3

It's a while I am working on a project with ionic-angular and cordova 
I use the latest version of ionic 3.6.0 and cordova 7.0.1
The problem is that on my android 4.4.4 it works perfectly, but I always get following errors on my android 6.1.0 for a reason I don't know:

```
file://android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1223 : deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds
file://android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1216 : channel not fired : onPluginsReady
file://android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1216 : channel not fired : onCordovaReady
file://android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1216 : channel not fired : onDOMContentLoaded
Channel not fired onCordovaReady:1216

file://android_asset/www/vendor.js: Line 1 : ERROR

file://android_asset/www/vendor.js: Line 1 : Ionic Native: deviceready did not fire whithin 5000ms. This can happen when plugins are in an inconsistent state try removing plugins from plugins/ and reinstalling them
```

the index.html in www directory content

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
        <head>
            <script data-ionic="inject">(function(w){var i=w.Ionic=w.Ionic||{};i.version='3.5.3';i.angular='4.1.3';i.staticDir='build/';})(window);
            </script>
           <meta charset="UTF-8">
           <title>Ionic App</title>
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.error('Error', err));
    }
  </script>-->

     <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body>

     <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
     <ion-app></ion-app>

     <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
     <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>
     <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>
     <!-- The bundle js is generated during the build process -->
     <script src="build/main.js"></script>

   </body>
</html>
```

Help please!

Comment: Can you show your `index.html` file on `www` folder?

Comment: @Sampath see edition for the index.html content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be solved finaly ,
I added the crosswalk plugin and it works now , but startup is very slow , it takes more than 1 minute

Answer (score 1):

Hope this may help you:

Open your project folder, find the plugin folder and delete it. Then try installing the plugins again using `cordova prepare` command. Finally run your project.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply , i'll just try it and get you back the result :)

Comment: I try it but i have always the same problem

It's probably due to the platform i use , but i not sur 
this is my config.xml whith platform
`<engine name="browser" spec="^4.1.0"/>
    <engine name="android" spec="~6.2.3"/>
  `

Comment: Try removing platform folder also `cordova platform remove android`. Then add it again `cordova platform add android`

Comment: Okay I'll try it just now

Answer (score 0):

go to the following file your-app-project/config.xml:

and change the value of loadUrlTimeoutValue to 700000

`<platform name="android">
        <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>`

if you don't have these lines just add them.

If this doesn't work I suspect you're using a plugin without waiting for the device to be ready.

Comment: I already had that in my config file , but still not working , I created new ionic project and  added android platform , and when  run it , I have the same error , It s probably a bug in my Android, because I try it on an other Android device , an Android 6 also , and it work perfectly